# Spring 4 Exception Handling : No suitable resolver for argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

**Problem Statement**

Migration to `Spring 4` from `Spring 3` induces some exceptions in exception handling flow.
  The Exception says `No suitable resolver for argument` in the `org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod` class.

So whenever and exception occurs `Spring` tries to find the Exception Handler which it gets
 but when it tries to populate the method arguments or exception Handler it throws the below exception

Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method:

```
  public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView  
       HelloController.handleCustomException(CustomGenericException, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView)

  java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
     No suitable resolver for argument [2] 
             [type=org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView]
```

HandlerMethod details:

```
Controller [HelloController]
Method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView  
        HelloController.handleCustomException(CustomGenericException,
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView)]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(
                     InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169)
```

It basically comes for `@CRequestParam("p") String p`  variable

**Code**

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/exception2")
    public String getException1(ModelMap model, @CRequestParam("p") String p) {

        System.out.println("Exception 2 "+ p);
        throw new CustomGenericException("1","2");
    }
```

Exception Handler

```
@ExceptionHandler(CustomGenericException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleCustomException(CustomGenericException ex, 
            HttpServletRequest request, @CRequestParam("p") String p) {

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error/generic_error");
            model.addObject("exception", ex);
            System.out.println("CustomGenericException  ");
            return model;
    }
```

Annotations

```
@Target( { ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface CRequestParam {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Param Resolver

```
public class CRequestparamResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {


    @Override
        public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
          CRequestParam requestParamAnnotation = 
          methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(CRequestParam.class);
        if(requestParamAnnotation==null){
        return false;
        }
        return true;
        }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

    CRequestParam requestParamAnnotation = methodParameter .getParameterAnnotation(CRequestParam.class);

    if (requestParamAnnotation != null) {
        String requestParamName = requestParamAnnotation.value();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(requestParamName)) {
        return webRequest.getParameter(requestParamName);
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

XML Configuration

```
<bean
        class="com.mkyong.common.resolver.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapterConfigurer"
        init-method="init">
        <property name="customArgumentResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.mkyong.common.resolver.CRequestparamResolver" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean 
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
        <property name="customArgumentResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.mkyong.common.resolver.CRequestparamResolver" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Source Code**

https://github.com/santoshjoshi/SpringMVC4

Comment: I presume that instead of `@CRequestParam` you mean `@RequestParam`

Comment: @geoand its custom request parameter `CRequestParam` for which we have `CRequestparamResolver` resolver.

Comment: @geoand the whole source code has now been checked in at `https://github.com/santoshjoshi/SpringMVC4`

Comment: Can you please post a more complete stacktrace?

Comment: AFAIK `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` does not handle the exception so it's argument resolvers cannot be used. Have a look at `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setArgumentResolvers()`. I never used it myself but it looks promising.

Comment: @geoand the whole exception code is available at `https://gist.github.com/santoshjoshi/31701ec034839ead3c7d`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved the problem by passing the custom arguments in request itself.

code is as  below :

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/exception2")
public String getException1(ModelMap model, @CRequestParam("p") String p, HttpServletRequest request) {

  System.out.println("Exception 2 " + p);
  request.setAttribute("p", p);
  throw new CustomGenericException("1", "2");
}
```

**Exception Handler**

```
@ExceptionHandler(CustomGenericException.class)
public ModelAndView handleCustomException(CustomGenericException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {

  ModelAndView model2 = new ModelAndView("error/generic_error");
  model2.addObject("exception", ex);
  System.out.println(request.getAttribute("p"));
  System.out.println("CustomGenericException  ");
  return model2;

}
```

**Complete source code** is available at [git](https://github.com/santoshjoshi/SpringMVC4)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I didn't add `@RequestBody` to my client-interface so it didn't know how to resolve the parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem  by providing the implementation of WebApplicationInitializer

```
public class SpringDispatcherConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext Contianer =   new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    Contianer.register(SpringConfig.class);
    Contianer.setServletContext(servletContext);
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(Contianer);
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("spring",dispatcherServlet);
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

}
```